# How can I trigger a YouTube video to play in browser on iOS by clicking on a play button instead of the embed?

Tags: ios, video, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

On my site, I want to have users watch an embedded YouTube video without leaving the page, but I don't want to have the not so stylistic YouTube embed visible prior to clicking.

This is entirely doable on desktop, as you can use the YouTube JavaScript API to trigger the embed to play, but on iOS, programmatic triggering of the player to play is blocked. So how can I do this on iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When thinking about this problem, I thought that one alternative route would be to have a layer that's opaque and styled, but you could click through it. This would mean the user thinks they're clicking a pretty button, when actually they're just clicking the embed to play.

Turns out there's a way of doing this, using the fancy (unofficial) CSS  `pointer-events` property! Setting this to `none` means that clicks don't register, and instead punch straight through the element to whatever is behind it. In this case, the YouTube embed iframe. Support is iOS 6+.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0a9fyvea/1/embedded/result/) of it working.

Note this is for iOS (and maybe Android) - it utilises the behaviour in which the video will automatically go full screen when it starts playing. If you watch this on desktop, the overlay remains..  overlaid.

There's some more polishing to be done with this to get it schmick:

- Handling the initial click and altering the UI so they know immediately the video is kicking off. Perhaps hide the overlay, fade it, or change it to simply signify "Loading... "
- On finish, resetting the video by recreating the iframe

You could do some tricky stuff with this technique, e.g. having a small player iframe overlaid by a small button. Still going to go fullscreen, so it'll work fine.

But regardless, there you go - proof of concept of playing a YouTube video on iOS without the user knowing they clicked on an embed.

Comment: unfortunately you can't handle the initial click because the whole point of `pointer-events: none` is that the click goes right through. you can handle all the youtube events, but in my experience it pretty much starts playing when the first event comes. also you might want to fade in the play button when the 'onready' event handler is called so people don't try to click before the video is loaded. this method has another advantage on desktop and mobile in that your view count will increment, which is doesn't for autoplay and API calls

Comment: also iOS 10 now allows inline playback, with the `playsinline: 1` initialization property so in that instance you need to hide the overlay when the video starts playing

Answer (score 0):

iOS allows to call `HTMLMediaElement.play` function only from dispatched (triggered) by an user event (for example, from a "click" event handler).
Thus the code like this will work in iOS (because the `player.playVideo` is called from the dispatched by an user "click" event):

```
<div class="video">
    <a href="#" class="play">Play</a>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pqLVAeoRavo?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen allow="autoplay"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
(function() {
    var player;
    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
        new YT.Player(document.querySelector('.video iframe'), {
            events: {
                onReady: function(e) {
                    player = e.target
                }
            }
        })
    }

    document.querySelector('.video .play').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        player.playVideo()
    })
})()
</script>
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

And the code like this will work in iOS too (because the initial call (the `playMyVideo()`) is still in the "click" event):

```
<div class="video">
    <a href="#" class="play">Play</a>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pqLVAeoRavo?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen allow="autoplay"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
(function() {
    var playMyVideo;
    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
        new YT.Player(document.querySelector('.video iframe'), {
            events: {
                onReady: function(e) {
                    playMyVideo = function() {
                        var player = e.target
                        player.playVideo()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

    document.querySelector('.video .play').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        playMyVideo()
    })
})()
</script>
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

**But the code like this will not work in iOS** (because the `player.playVideo` is called from the `https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api` script and not from the "click" event; i.e. only the `window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` function declaration is presented in the "click" event and `window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` is called from the `https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api` script):

```
<div class="video">
    <a href="#" class="play">Play</a>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pqLVAeoRavo?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen allow="autoplay"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
(function() {
    document.querySelector('.video .play').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
            new YT.Player(document.querySelector('.video iframe'), {
                events: {
                    onReady: function(e) {
                        var player = e.target
                        player.playVideo()
                    }
                }
            })
        }

        var tag = document.createElement('script')
        tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag)
    })
})()
</script>
```